# Couldn't open device eth0: eth0: socket: Invalid argument

Tags: c, linux, client, dhcp

I am trying to use a simple [DHCP client](https://github.com/samueldotj/dhcp-client) from GitHub. When I try to run this client it fails with

```
eth0 MAC : C8:6B:00:E5:52:5E
Couldn't open device eth0: eth0: socket: Invalid argument
```

Any advices?
Thanks!

Comment: maybe you need to run as root?

Comment: Please reduce it to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly `pcap_open_live()` returns with `NULL`.

> `pcap_open_live()` returns a `pcap_t *` on success and `NULL` on
>   failure. If `NULL` is returned, `errbuf` is filled in with an
>   appropriate error message. `errbuf` may also be set to warning text
>   when `pcap_open_live()` succeds; to detect this case the caller should
>   store a zero-length string in `errbuf` before calling
>   `pcap_open_live()` and display the warning to the user if `errbuf`is
>   no longer a zero-length string. `errbuf`is assumed to be able to hold
>   at least `PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE` chars.

You may want to investigate your card.

Check as root:

```
su -c "lspci | grep -i ether"
```

Check that this device is in fact `eth0`

```
/usr/sbin/ethtool -i eth0
```

and

```
dmesg | grep eth0
```

Comment: Well, I've tried all of these commands on my Ubuntu and VM(Fedora). My results:          su -c "lspci | grep -i ether"
00:03.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)

Comment: /usr/sbin/ethtool -i enp0s3
driver: e1000
version: 7.3.21-k8-NAPI
firmware-version: 
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:00:03.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no

Comment: dmesg | grep enp0s3
[    2.379258] e1000 0000:00:03.0 enp0s3: renamed from eth0
[   25.205919] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s3: link is not ready
[   25.207815] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s3: link is not ready
[   25.208355] e1000: enp0s3 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
[   25.208643] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s3: link becomes ready

Comment: @JebuNato Try to use `enp0s3` in `argv[1];` , also looks like there is some initial problem with the link `"enp0s3: link is not ready"`